# Taken by itself plural

Tags: grammar, vocabulary

I want to express that there are clear differences in salaries between two cities, but if we look at the salaries in one city taken by itself, there is already an important insight. Checking the internet I could not find anything on how to express *taken by itself* or *alone* in plural.

Some ideas:

While salaries between New York and Washington are clearly different, salaries in New York have an extremely high fixed rate *by themselves*.

While salaries between New York and Washington are clearly different, salaries in New York *alone* have an extremely high fixed rate.

While salaries between New York and Washington are clearly different, salaries in New York have an extremely high fixed rate *taken by themselves*.

While salaries between New York and Washington are clearly different, salaries *only* in New York have an extremely high fixed rate.

Which sounds best/which is right?

Comment: "salaries only in New York" is my favorite. It is concise and clear.

Comment: It probably doesn't make sense to say that salaries in New York are "high" unless you're comparing them to salaries in other places, or to cost of living, or to historical salaries, or something like that.

Comment: @Juhasz fair, but I am more concerned about the grammar here than the content

Comment: short follow-up question: is "by themselves" generally incorrect? I mean as the plural to "by itself", which according to a dictionary can be used to refer to "seen individually".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"While salary rates in New York and Washington are clearly different, when considered in isolation, salaries in New York are extremely high."